# How can I optimize this function which is related to reversal of string?

Tags: python, reverse

I have a string: "String"
The first thing you do is reverse it: "gnirtS"
Then you will take the string from the 1st position and reverse it again: "gStrin"
Then you will take the string from the 2nd position and reverse it again: "gSnirt"
Then you will take the string from the 3rd position and reverse it again: "gSntri"
Continue this pattern until you have done every single position, and then you will return the string you have created. For this particular string, you would return: "gSntir"

And I have to repeat this entire procedure for x times where the string and x can be very big . (million or billion)

My code is working fine for small strings but it's giving timeout error for very long strings.

```
def string_func(s,x):
    def reversal(st):
        n1=len(st)
        for i in range(0,n1):
            st=st[0:i]+st[i:n1][::-1]
        return st
    for i in range(0,x):
        s=reversal(s)
    return s
```

Comment: I don't understand `"I have to repeat this entire procedure for x times where the string and x can be very big . (million or billion)"` Why would you need to keep going if the string is already reversed? will you really have a string with billion characters?

Comment: Do you explicitly need to use recursion? what's wrong with `str.reverse`?

Comment: Repeat the process manually for a couple of string and compare input and output. You will quickly see a pattern. When you see a pattern, you will be able to implement the algorithm in O(N).

Comment: Note that you describe an algorithm to get a particular result. Your goal here is to find a different algorithm that gives the same results for all possible inputs. As Sergey says, you need to play with several examples and look for a pattern that allows you to write a completely different algorithm that is more efficient. For example, try applying your algorithm to `"Hello, World!" by hand.

Comment: Appears to be from the [String -> X-Iterations -> String](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5ae64f28d2ee274164000118) kata on Codewars, just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

This linear implementation could point you in the right direction:

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import cycle

def special_reverse(s):
    d, res = deque(s), []
    ops = cycle((d.pop, d.popleft))
    while d:
        res.append(next(ops)())
    return ''.join(res)
```

You can recognize the slice patterns in the following examples:

```
>>> special_reverse('123456')
'615243'
>>> special_reverse('1234567')
'7162534'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
my_string = "String"
my_string_len = len(my_string)

result = ""

for i in range(my_string_len):
    my_string = my_string[::-1]
    result += my_string[0]
    my_string = my_string[1:]

print(result)
```

And this, though it looks spaghetti :D

```
s = "String"
lenn = len(s)
resultStringList = []

first_half = list(s[0:int(len(s) / 2)])
second_half = None
middle = None

if lenn % 2 == 0:
    second_half = list(s[int(len(s) / 2) : len(s)][::-1])
else:
    second_half = list(s[int(len(s) / 2) + 1 : len(s)][::-1])
    middle = s[int(len(s) / 2)]
    lenn -= 1

for k in range(int(lenn / 2)):
    print(k)
    resultStringList.append(second_half.pop(0))
    resultStringList.append(first_half.pop(0))

if middle != None:
    resultStringList.append(middle)

print(''.join(resultStringList))
```

Answer (score 0):

or a short version using iterator magic:

```
def string_func(s):
    ops = (iter(reversed(s)), iter(s))
    return ''.join(next(ops[i % 2]) for i in range(len(s)))
```

which does the right thing for me, while if you're happy using some library code, you can golf it down to:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def string_func(s):
    ops = (iter(reversed(s)), iter(s))
    return ''.join(map(next, islice(cycle(ops), len(s))))
```

my original version takes 80microseconds for a 512 character string, this updated version takes 32µs, while your version took 290µs and schwobaseggl's solution is about 75µs.

I've had a play in Cython and I can get runtime down to ~0.5µs.  Measuring this under [`perf_event_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) I can see my CPU is retiring ~8 instructions per character, which seems pretty good, while a hard-coded loop in C gets this down to ~4.5 instructions per ASCII `char`.  These don't seem to be very "Pythonic" solutions so I'll leave them out of this answer.  But included this paragraph to show that the OP has options to make things faster, and that running this a billion times on a string consisting of ~500 characters will still take hundreds of seconds even with relatively careful C code.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your solution is correct there is no doubt about it but I have to repeat this entire  string_func(st)  for "n" times. So while doing this I am getting a timeout error .As I have to make another for loop for repeating this procedure for "n" times .So, in any case, is it possible to optimize it more.

Answer (score 0):

From the pattern of the original string and the result I constructed this algorithm. It has minimal number of operations.

```
str = 'Strings'
lens = len(str)
lensh = int(lens/2)
nstr = ''
for i in range(lensh):
    nstr = nstr + str[lens - i - 1] + str[i]

if ((lens % 2) == 1):
    nstr = nstr + str[lensh]

print(nstr)
```